# Unable to compile the react.js code . Getting error at line No. 7

Tags: reactjs

Unable to compile the react.js code . Getting error at line No. 7. Below is my code and error. I have created react app through create-react-app.

```
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand } from 'reactstrap';
import Menu from './components/MenuComponents';
import './App.css';
import { DISHES } from './shared/dishes';

function App() {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dishes: DISHES
    };
  }
  return(
    <div>
      < Navbar dark color = "success">
        <div className="container">
            <NavbarBrand href ="/">Restaurant Confusion</NavbarBrand>          
        </div>
      </Navbar>
      <Menu dishes={this.state.dishes} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Kindly Guide Me. Below is the error.

```
Failed to compile.

./src/App.js
SyntaxError: D:\Development Section\Git-Repositories\Full-Stack-Web-Development\React.js\src\App.js: Unexpected token, expected ";" (7:22)

   5 |
   6 | function App() {
>  7 |     constructor(props){
     |                       ^
   8 |     super(props);
   9 |     this.state = {
  10 |       dishes: DISHES
```

Comment: Why do you have a `constructor` inside a `function`?

Comment: Then where i should have included it

Comment: You should use a hook like `React.useState` to maintain state in a function component. Get rid of the constructor. See the documentation on function components.

Comment: Can you help me in resolving the error

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a class based component if you would like to use the contructor.

class based components are created as below

```js
import React from "react";
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dishes: DISHES,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar dark color="success">
          <div className="container">
            <NavbarBrand href="/">Restaurant Confusion</NavbarBrand>
          </div>
        </Navbar>
        <Menu dishes={this.state.dishes} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: After using the above code getting the below error.

Comment: Attempted import error: './components/MenuComponents' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Menu').

Answer (score 0):

In case you want it to be a functional component:

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand } from 'reactstrap';
import Menu from './components/MenuComponents';
import './App.css';
import { DISHES } from './shared/dishes';

function App() {
  const[dishes,setDishes]=useState(DISHES);
  return(
    <div>
      < Navbar dark color = "success">
        <div className="container">
            <NavbarBrand href ="/">Restaurant Confusion</NavbarBrand>          
        </div>
      </Navbar>
      <Menu dishes={dishes} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Getting the below error after trying the above code.

Comment: Failed to compile.

./src/App.js
Attempted import error: './components/MenuComponents' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Menu').

Comment: that is error with your MenuComponents file.if for once try removing `import Menu from './components/MenuComponents';` and `<Menu dishes={dishes} />` from your code,the error should go.

Comment: can you help me with MenuComponents file

Comment: I found the error and issue is resolved Thanks for your help